# :helloWorld:preDexDebug trouble writing output: null FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just created a new helloworld project and hit build and deploy on my AVD and getting this error

full stack trace of gradle console is as follows

```
Executing tasks: [:helloWorld:assembleDebug]

Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:helloWorld:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900Library UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:prepareDebugDependencies
:helloWorld:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:helloWorld:preDexDebug

trouble writing output: null
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':helloWorld:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloWorld\helloWorld\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-03192f978c99c1af96ffa2bf67c8f95252f876bd.jar C:\Users\ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloWorld\helloWorld\build\exploded-bundles\ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900.aar\classes.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:

    trouble writing output: null
```

Comment: Please attach your build.gradle file.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of solving this issue?

Comment: As far as I know, I did couple of things like cleaning up and fresh build, restarting IDE, renaming the main activity, and also installing fresh AVD... and one of them fixed the issue... I am sorry but its a long time and I don't remember the correct solution.